# the content inside the Accordion MUI is compressed too much

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, accordion

i have Accordion from material ui (MUI) with text field inside. but after the element is expanded, the text field is compressed and does not take up the entire width

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      height: 150,
    },
  })
);

export function AccordionCustom(props: PropsWithChildren<AccordionProps>) {
  return (
    <Accordion classes={useStyles.root}>
      <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
        <label>{props.title}</label>
      </AccordionSummary>
      <AccordionDetails>{props.children}</AccordionDetails>
    </Accordion>
  );
}
```

```
        <AccordionCustom title='Title'>
          <TextField
            sx={{ minHeight: 300 }}
            variant='outlined'
            label='title'
            value={location?.title}
            onChange={(e) => handleInputChange('description', e.target.value)}
          />
        </AccordionCustom>
```

[image]

[image]

i tried override root style for Accordion but i see that is legacy, and i tried to customize text field width but it still looks like bad